# When I set a property in code does it matter if the storyboard option is enabled or disabled?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard, settings

Consider `UITableView`'s refreshing option.

If I have code in place to set up and display a refresher, should I keep it enabled or disabled in storyboard (With the little check-boxes)?
I figure it is not usually critical, but I would imagine that there are certain things that can cause bugs when overlooked, like if setting the refresher as 'off' in storyboard also changed some scrolling properties that were not covered in code (even though it doesn't-).

I am presuming that written code takes priority over storyboard options, and any storyboard settings are configured at compile time.

Is something that I need to be concerned with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every change you do in your `UIViewController`s method `-(void)viewDidLoad` will be performed after the view has been loaded, so it will override the Storyboard/nib settings. And from this point on, all the code changes should be preserved (maybe some layout code can be problematic because of Auto-Layout etc.)

As the [UIViewController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad) says:

> **viewDidLoad**
>
> Called after the controller’s view is loaded into memory.
>
> ```
> - (void)viewDidLoad
> ```
>
> This method is called after the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory. This method is called regardless of whether the view hierarchy was loaded from a nib file or created programmatically in the loadView method. You usually override this method to perform additional initialization on views that were loaded from nib files.